# C (linux) - Emulate / Skip scanf input

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, scanf

I have a program running 2 threads. The first is waiting for user input (using a scanf), the second is listening for some data over an udp socket. I would like to emulate user input to handle a specific notification with the first thread everytime I recive a specific udp packet. I know I can share variables between threads, so my question is: can I force the scanf to take input from a different thread? Can I skip the scanf in the first thread?

Comment: Use a pipe between the threads.

Comment: A pipe is pretty expensive, isn't there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe scanf() by definition reads from stdin. Like you said, though, the different threads share memory so it's easy to pass information between them. Maybe have some shared variable and some sort of boolean value indicating whether or not the information has been updated from the thread reading from the network. It all depends on what you're specifically trying to do, but you may want to have some other mechanism for simulation that bypasses the scanf().

Comment: I'm trying to notify the first thread that the second received a specific packet. The problem is that I want the first thread to wait the user input, so it's blocked by the scanf. Another way to do it, is creating a third thread, but it's pretty expensive.

Comment: Since there isn't really a non-blocking form of scanf(), I think the simplest way (agreed, a little expensive but much simpler logically) would be to have one thread simply performing the scanf() and writing the results to some shared buffer that other threads can access. Then you could have the logic in another thread that can also write to this shared buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've specifically mentioned Linux, I'm going to suggest a novelty here.

You can open `(/proc/%d/fd/%d, getpid(), STDIN_FILENO)` and write to it. This will actually open the input of the terminal. I wouldn't recommend this for a real program, but then again, `scanf` shouldn't be used in real programs either.

Comment: Note that you'll be out of luck if actual user input comes on `stdin` at the same time you're writing to the new fd.

Comment: Why not? So I should replace scanf with something else?

Comment: Get whatever data you need to retrieve and stuff it inside a buffer; and then call `sscanf` or similar to parse it into its constituent parts. Then you would use `select()` or similar in your code for both the UDP socket and the stdin file descriptor (Linux lets you select many types of file descriptors, not only sockets)